# Is there a way to find all the relations that exists between two entities?

Tags: google-api, ontology, google-search

I need to populate an ontology in the domain of Music Artists. To get an understanding of the domain which I should populate, I need to find out,

1) All the possible objects related to the particular artist. (Song, Album, Movie etc.)
2) All the possible relations between this celebrity and the object. (Singer  Object).

Is there any way to do this manually or through Google API?(I tried this manually by giving this on the google search bar. But it is a hard task to do it manually. Though if there is a way to speed this up, it would be sufficient at the moment.)

Comment: I am not aware that ontologies can be queried through the google-api. For that you will most likely need semantic web technology tools like Protege, Jena, the OWL api.

Comment: No. I do not need to query an ontology yet. To populate knowledge to an ontology I need to get an idea of the knowledge I should populate. To do that I need to find out all the objects related to music artists. Is there any way to do this manually or through an API?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a way to query the web which will combine results from various websites and web pages and present a combined and coherent result to you based on your query. Currently this cannot be done for the web in general. However, the **semantic web** is an area of research that is trying to achieve exactly that.

Using semantic web technology it is possible to do such queries for parts of the web. [DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/about) is a prominent semantic web project that aims to enable arbitrary queries across Wikipedia. DBPedia provides a [live end-point](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql) that you can query using [SPARQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/). Referring to [DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/about) will give you a brief overview of how this all fits together.

Accessing the [live end-point](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql) you can run the following SPARQL-query that will give a list of musicians. Clicking on the links in the result page will provide you with more information on each musician.

```
SELECT ?subject
WHERE {
   ?subject a dbo:MusicalArtist .
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Found a method to retrieve entities related to a particular object through google knowledge graph API.

[Google Knowledge Graph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/#sample_request)